# Error uploading Sonar report: Sonar Scan - 500

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using SonarQube 6.7 LTS version and facing this below error. Quick search in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701160/error-uploading-sonnar-report) shows issue occurs when SonarQube generates a huge report and then tries to upload it in one shot, causing HTTP 500, But we are using POstgreSQL DB (version 9.6.5) already. Anyone has any idea how this can be addressed for PostgreSQL DB?

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project myApplicationsonar-project: Failed to upload report - 500: An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project myApplicationsonar-project: Failed to upload report - 500: An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to upload report - 500: An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 31 more
Caused by: Failed to upload report - 500: An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we managed to resolve the issue. 
We reset shared_buffers parameter on PostgreSQL side to higher value (8 GB). Despite of that there was an error and this time we had below error entry in web.log.

```
ERROR web[AWkvYxqZhvRO95YsAfgm][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://mysonar/sonar/api/ce/submit?projectKey=myProject&projectName=myProject
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "myProject" key matches multiple permission templates: "template1", "template2". A system administrator must update these templates so that only one of them matches the key.
```

Resolving conflict in permission template resolved the issue completely.